# Why is the 'Quantity' value not displaying any value?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to display the Quantity value from a database table, but it's not showing the `$quantity` value in the browser. Why?

[image]

```
<?php

include('connection.php');

# cartexe.php will perform all actions on cart.php

// add Item to Cart
if(isset($_POST['addItemToCart']))
{
    // initialize index.php variables
    $productName = $_POST['productName'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $quantity = 0;

    // check the cart table to see if the product has been previously added
    $smtp = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM cart WHERE Product_Name = :product'); // prepare a statement to fetch the quanity for a particular pprodut... the statement is not executed but merely prepared to do so. 
    $smtp->bindParam(':product', $productName, PDO::PARAM_STR); //bind the productNAme with whatever data supplied hence the statement after : above will be replaced with the actually data.. In additional the statement is set as string hence PDO::PRAM_STR
    $smtp->execute();//finally run the statment

    //var_dump($smtp);
    //find the number of rows affected
    $result = $smtp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    // var_dump($smtp);


    //the data does existed
    if($result > 0)
    {
        $row = $smtp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo " DATA FOUND";
        echo $row['Quantity'];

        //$quantity++; // increment the quanity if data found
     }
     //no match found
     else
     {
         echo ' No data found';
     }

 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Does it echo no data found?

Comment: It echos DATA FOUND!

Comment: after `echo $row['Quantity'];` add `var_dump($row,$productName);` lets us see what you get.

Comment: @BojanT `bool(false) string(7) "product"`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: @zerkms I'm a rookie on PDO. Not sure which error handling to try and how to apply it to the code ... mind elaborating on which to use? The default sounds about right.

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight: see the first example on that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't need first fetch try

```
$smtp = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM cart WHERE Product_Name = :product'); // prepare a statement to fetch the quanity for a particular pprodut... the statement is not executed but merely prepared to do so. 
    $smtp->bindParam(':product', $productName, PDO::PARAM_STR); //bind the productNAme with whatever data supplied hence the statement after : above will be replaced with the actually data.. In additional the statement is set as string hence PDO::PRAM_STR
   ;//finally run the statment



    //the data does existed
    if( $smtp->execute() )
    {
        $row = $smtp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo " DATA FOUND";
        echo $row['Quantity'];

        //$quantity++; // increment the quanity if data found
     }
```

Comment: Thanks alot, really appreciate your solution!

Answer (score 1):

looks like PDO does not let you fetch twice, it return the result only the first time, then it just returns false

```
$result = $smtp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // returns result
$result = $smtp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // returns false
```

so, the one solution is simply

```
$result = $smtp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($result != false){
//....
```